# check the filesystem percentage and run script with case commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, switch-statement

i am new to bash scripting, trying to run the below script where i should check the system percentage and run the another script using case command

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "will able to see the percentage of hard disk"
for line in $(</home/AAA/BBB/CCCC/pre-prod1.txt)
do
ssh $line 'hostname -s; df -P |grep '/XXX/CCCC' | awk '"'"'{print $5}'"'"
echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
usage = $(< 'hostname -s; df -P |grep '/opt/splunk' | awk '"'"'{print $5}'"'" )
#if [$? -gt 65]
#   then
#        '/home/ BB/DD /remove_old_data.sh'
#
#fi
done

case $usage in
     50% - 2880 minutes) echo "when the hard disk is above 50%"
         /home/BB/DD/remove_old_data.sh 2880
          ;;
     50-75% - 1440 minutes) echo "when the hard disk space is above 75%"
         /home/ BB/DD /remove_old_data.sh 1440
         ;;
     75-90% - 720 minutes) echo "when the hard disk space is above 90%"
        /home/ BB/DD /remove_old_data.sh 720
        ;;
     >90% - 360 minutes) echo "when the hard disk space above 91%"
        /home/ BB/DD /remove_old_data.sh 360
       ;;
esac
```

i am getting the below error :

```
./checksize1.sh: line 9: hostname -s; df -P |grep /opt/splunk | awk '{print $5}': No such file or directory
./checksize1.sh: line 9: usage: command not found
./checksize1.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `-'
./checksize1.sh: line 19: `     50% - 2880 minutes) echo "when the hard disk is above 50%"'
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: quote the cases the dash  is interpreted

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications in your script and it should fulfill your requirement:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "will able to see the percentage of hard disk"
for line in $(cat /home/AAA/BBB/CCCC/pre-prod1.txt)
do 
usage=$(ssh $line "df -P |grep '/opt/splunk'" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
#if [$? -gt 65]
#   then
#        '/home/ BB/DD /remove_old_data.sh'
#
#fi
echo "Machine name: $( echo $line | cut -d'@' -f2 )"
    case $usage in
         50 ) echo "when the hard disk is above 50%"
            /home/BB/DD/remove_old_data.sh 2880
            ;;
         [5-6][0-9]|7[0-5] ) echo "when the hard disk space is above 75%"
             /home/BB/DD/remove_old_data.sh 1440
            ;;
         7[6-9]|8[0-9]|90 ) echo "when the hard disk space is above 90%"
            /home/BB/DD/remove_old_data.sh 720
            ;;
         9[1-9]|100 ) echo "when the hard disk space above 91%"
            /home/BB/DD/remove_old_data.sh 360
            ;;
          * ) echo "Disk space is less than 50%"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

The file `/home/AAA/BBB/CCCC/pre-prod1.txt` should contain the hostnames of the server like below:

```
user@server1
user@server2
user@server3
```

Please check this and let me know if your requirement is something else.

*NOTE*: I have updated the script. Previously, I had given partition as `/dev/sda1`, however, I believe you are trying to get the disk usage of the partition `/opt/splunk`. I have made changes in my script and this should work fine. In case, you are trying to get disk usage of any other partition on the servers, please update in the below line in script:

```
usage=$(ssh $line "df -P |grep '/opt/splunk'" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
```

I have tested the script now on test servers and found the below results.

```
[12:41]✓ -> bash test.sh 
will able to see the percentage of hard disk
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Server: server1 
82
when the hard disk space is above 90%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Server: server2
87
when the hard disk space is above 90%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Server: server3
50
when the hard disk is above 50%
```

Comment: Thanks for the script,

Comment: please find the below error : will able to see the percentage of hard disk
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
./checksize1.sh: line 14: abc.sec.xyz.com: command not found
 hostname:
Disk space is less than 50%

Comment: My system name are abcd.zxc.xzy.com and i many system in that , and when i check the disk percentage one of the system its above than 50% but still i got the above error.

Comment: Sorry, there was a small mistake in the script in line 14. I have modified the script and it should work now.

Comment: Thanks for the script, i am able to run the script but if the hard disk usage above 50% or below 50% i am getting output of "Disk space is less than 50% "  and it should run the second script also also according to output which we get. anymore suggestion

Comment: i have unchecked comment also, the second script is not working and the output i get is "Disk space is less than 50%" for all the systems where i run the script few are below 50% and few above 50% , they run the second script accordingly the number specficed

Comment: @GeraldJohnson I checked and found that the script had `/dev/sda1` partition and also there was a small issue. I have modified the script and tested as well. Please see the `NOTE` added at the end of my answer. If you are still having any issues, I will be happy to help.

Comment: please find the script which i had modified

Comment: i am unable to post the script so i am raising the another quest with the script and output